# Python code about guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a little problem with my code, i'm trying to make a guess game, actually it is from a book, but i can't figure out what is wrong with it...

```
# A guess game program made in python
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name, may i ask?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + myName + ', I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20')

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess..')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your number guess is too low, guess again')

    if guess > number:
        print('Your number is too high! guess lower or something!')

    if guess == number:
        break

    if guess == number:
        guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
        print('Good job, ' + myName + '! You guessed the right number in' + guessesTaken + 'guesses!')

    if guess != number:
            number = str(number)
            print('Nah, The number i was thinking of was ' + number)
```

This is the error it's giving me..

```
Hello! What is your name, may i ask?
ygh
Well, ygh, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20
Take a guess..
4
Your number guess is too low, guess again
Nah, The number i was thinking of was 7
Take a guess..
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/guess.py", line 19, in <module>
    if guess < number:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using Pycharm as my IDLE and i'm also on windows..

Comment: `number = str(number)` That's your issue. After that, number is a string, so you can't compare it to a number. Move the call to `str` inside the call to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Few changes in your code tho, instead of calling `str` you can use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting)

```
# A guess game program made in python
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Hello! What is your name, may i ask?')
myName = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, {}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20'.format(myName))

while guessesTaken < 6:
    print('Take a guess..')
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    guessesTaken += 1 # Instead of calling the variable itself then adding 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your number guess is too low, guess again')

    if guess > number:
        print('Your number is too high! guess lower or something!')

    if guess == number:
        print('Good job, {}! You guessed the right number in {} guesses!'.format(myName,guessesTaken))
        break # the beak goes here

    if guess != number:
        print('Nah, The number i was thinking of was {}'.format(number))
```

Also, your `break` was placed incorrectly because it will be executed before sending the `print` that you want, thus ending your code prematurely.